# Integration Test to publish to a topic and subscribe to another in Azure Service Bus is unreliable is there a race condition?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, message-queue, azure-servicebus-topics

I am trying to write an integration / acceptance test to test some code in azure, the code in the question ATM simply subscribes to one topic and publishes to another.

I have written the test but it doesn't always pass, seems as though there could be a race condition in place.  I've tried writing it a couple of ways including using OnMessage and also using Receive (example I show here).

When using OnMessage the test seemed to always exit prematurely (around 30 seconds), which I guess perhaps means its inappropriate for this test anyway.

My query concerning my example specifically, I assumed that once I created the subscription to the target topic, that any message sent to it I would be able to pickup using Receive(), whatever point in time that message arrived meaning, if the message arrives at the target topic before I call Receive(), I would still be able to read the message afterward by calling Receive().  Could anyone please shed any light on this?

```
    namespace somenamespace {
    [TestClass]
    public class SampleTopicTest
    {
        private static TopicClient topicClient;
        private static SubscriptionClient subClientKoEligible;
        private static SubscriptionClient subClientKoIneligible;

        private static OnMessageOptions options;
        public const string TEST_MESSAGE_SUB = "TestMessageSub";
        private static NamespaceManager namespaceManager;

        private static string topicFleKoEligible;
        private static string topicFleKoIneligible;

        private BrokeredMessage message;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void BeforeClass(TestContext testContext)
        {
            //client for publishing messages
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusConnectionString"];
            string topicDataReady = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataReadyTopicName"];
            topicClient = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topicDataReady);

            topicFleKoEligible = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KnockOutEligibleTopicName"];
            topicFleKoIneligible = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KnockOutIneligibleTopicName"];

            //create test subscription to receive messages
            namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);


            if (!namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(topicFleKoEligible, TEST_MESSAGE_SUB))
            {
                namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(topicFleKoEligible, TEST_MESSAGE_SUB);
            }

            if (!namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(topicFleKoIneligible, TEST_MESSAGE_SUB))
            {
                namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(topicFleKoIneligible, TEST_MESSAGE_SUB);
            }

            //subscriber client koeligible
            subClientKoEligible = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topicFleKoEligible, TEST_MESSAGE_SUB);

            subClientKoIneligible = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topicFleKoIneligible, TEST_MESSAGE_SUB);

            options = new OnMessageOptions()
            {
                AutoComplete = false,
                AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),

            };
        }

          [TestMethod]
        public void E2EPOCTopicTestLT50()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string customerId = rnd.Next(1, 49).ToString();

            FurtherLendingCustomer sentCustomer = new FurtherLendingCustomer { CustomerId = customerId };
            BrokeredMessage sentMessage = new BrokeredMessage(sentCustomer.ToJson());           
            sentMessage.CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string messageId = sentMessage.MessageId;
            topicClient.Send(sentMessage);

            Boolean messageRead = false;

            //wait for message to arrive on the ko eligible queue
            while((message = subClientKoEligible.Receive(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))) != null){

                //read message
                string messageString = message.GetBody<String>();

                //Serialize
                FurtherLendingCustomer receivedCustomer =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FurtherLendingCustomer>(messageString.Substring(messageString.IndexOf("{")));

                //assertion
                Assert.AreEqual(sentCustomer.CustomerId, receivedCustomer.CustomerId,"verify customer id");

                //pop message
                message.Complete();
                messageRead = true;

                //leave loop after processing one message
                break;
            }
            if (!messageRead)
                Assert.Fail("Didn't receive any message after 2 mins");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the official document states about [SubscriptionClient.Receive(TimeSpan)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.receive?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_SubscriptionClient_Receive_System_TimeSpan_):

> Parameters
>   **serverWaitTime**
>   TimeSpan
>
> The time span the server waits for receiving a message before it times out.
>
> **A Null can be return by this API if operation exceeded the timeout specified, or the operations succeeded but there are no more messages to be received**.

Per my test, if a message sent to the topic and then delivered to your subscription within your specific serverWaitTime, then you could receive a message no matter whether the message arrives at the target topic before or after you call `Receive`.

> When using OnMessage the test seemed to always exit prematurely (around 30 seconds), which I guess perhaps means its inappropriate for this test anyway.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ReceiveMessages()
{
    subClient.OnMessage(msg => {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation($"{DateTime.Now}：{msg.GetBody<string>()}");
        msg.Complete();
    });
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)).Wait();
}
```

[image]

For [Subscription​Client.​On​Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.onmessage?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_SubscriptionClient_OnMessage_System_Action_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage__Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_OnMessageOptions_), I assumed that it basically a loop invoking `Receive`. After calling `OnMessage`, you need to wait for a while and stop this method to exit. Here is a blog about the Event-Driven message programming for windows Azure Service Bus, you could refer to [here](http://fabriccontroller.net/introducing-the-event-driven-message-programming-model-for-the-windows-azure-service-bus/).

Additionally, I found that your `topicClient` for sending messages and the `subClientKoEligible` for receiving a message are not targeted at the same topic path.